# Accumulators in Spark (PySpark) without global variables?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-hadoop, pyspark

**BACKGROUND**

Consider the following textbook example which uses accumulators to add vectors.

```
from pyspark import AccumulatorParam

class VectorAccumulatorParam(AccumulatorParam):

    def zero(self, value):

        dict1 = {i: 0 for i in range(0, len(value))}

        return dict1

    def addInPlace(self, val1, val2):

        for i in val1.keys():
            val1[i] += val2[i]

        return val1

rdd1 = sc.parallelize([{0: 0.3, 1: 0.8, 2: 0.4}, 
                       {0: 0.2, 1: 0.4, 2: 0.2},
                       {0: -0.1, 1: 0.4, 2: 1.6}])

vector_acc = sc.accumulator({0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0}, 
                            VectorAccumulatorParam())

def mapping_fn(x):

    global vector_acc

    vector_acc += x

rdd1.foreach(mapping_fn)
print(vector_acc.value)
```

This prints `{0: 0.4, 1: 1.6, 2: 2.2}`, i.e., the element-wise sum of the vectors.

**QUESTION**

The use of the `global` scope in `mapping_fn()` gnaws at me, since it's usually bad practice. Is there a simple way to illustrate how accumulators work without resorting to a global variable? This is all the more confusing since, as far as I understand, the beauty of Spark lies in a *share nothing* philosophy, and `global` is precisely the opposite of that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with sharing nothing is that for reduce functions like sum you need results from multiple elements. There are Spark ways to do this and there is also a sum already implemented, but the easiest code for reduction is using variables and looping. You need to get used to functional programming that Spark uses in order to write Spark way code. Functional programming also allows easier parallelization and faster distributed code.

It would probably be faster to use Spark dataframes like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51007017/how-to-sum-many-columns-in-pyspark-dataframe). And in my opinion they are easier to understand than map-reduce logic.

A possible map-reduce approach (this is how the whole code looks like):

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([{0: 0.3, 1: 0.8, 2: 0.4}, 
                       {0: 0.2, 1: 0.4, 2: 0.2},
                       {0: -0.1, 1: 0.4, 2: 1.6}])

def acc_fn(acc, row):
    res = {}
    for key,value in row.items():
        res[key] = acc[key] + value
    return res

vector_acc = rdd1.reduce(acc_fn)

print(vector_acc)
```

`vector_acc` is now defined as a Python dictionary and not a class. You should access it as a dictionary.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean? ``mapping_fn()`` is supposed to return a value in order to be used by ``lambda``. What value is it returning? As you can see from my code, all that ``mapping_fn()`` does is to return the global ``vector_acc``, it does not do anything to ``x``.

Comment: In other words, could you give the definition of ``mapping_fn()``? Otherwise, the call of ``foreach()`` on its own doesn't make sense.

Comment: You are right. I still needed to return the variable and foreach does not allow this. I changed my answer accordingly and translated map-reduce logic to your data. I still think that dataframes are the right way to do it. They translate all python code into Scala and it should become significantly faster than the code you provided. And I did not check the code. Feel free to comment if it does not work.

Comment: I get the error `'dict' object has no attribute 'value'` when running `vector_acc.value`. Basically, all I want is to get rid of the `global` scope, but keep everything else as simple as possible.

Comment: Right. `vector_acc` is not a class anymore. It is a dictionary. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `global`. You can simply reference `vector_acc` in this function and it will serialize with the function. Spark will handle getting updates made on the executors back to the driver. I am not sure what the purpose of `global` is here.